# login form with ajax and django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

My app has a the login option, i am trying when the user sumbit the login form, this validate and if is not right say something like user and password doesnt exist, but without my main page reload or redirect to another page, the login form is in the same index page

**view.py**

```
@ajax_request 
def index(request):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, Estado=False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formlog = LoginUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formlog.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = formlog.clean_data
            username = cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(nombre_de_usuario=username, password=password) 
            if user is not None: 
                if user.is_active: 
                    login(request, user) 
                    return {"status" : "true"} 
                else: 
                    return {"status" : "false", "reason" : "You need to activate your account. Please check your email"} 
            else:
                return {"status" : "false", "reason" : "Invalid username/password"}
        else:
            formlog = LoginUserForm()
    else:
        formlog = LoginUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            username = cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')
            user_model = MiUsuario.objects.create_user(nombre_de_usuario=username, email=email, password=password)
            user_model.save()
        else:
            form = RegistroUserForm()
    else: 
        form = RegistroUserForm()
    context = {
        'formlog' : formlog,
        'form': form,
        'notifi': notifi,
        'year' : datetime.now().year,
    }

    return render(request,'app/index.html',context)
```

i am using the Ajax from the views

**form.py**

```
class LoginUserForm(AuthenticationForm):
    """Authentication form which uses boostrap CSS."""
    username = forms.CharField(label=_(""),max_length=254,widget=forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Nombre de usuario'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label=_(""),widget=forms.PasswordInput({'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Contraseña'}))
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if MiUsuario.objects.filter(nombre_de_usuario!=username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Nombre de usuario no existe.')
        return username
    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        if MiUsuario.objects.filter(password!=password):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Contraseña incorrecta.')
        return password
```

**login.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/login"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
        {{ formlog.username }}
        <div class="text-danger">
            {%if form.errors %}
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">{{forms.ValidationError}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
        {{ formlog.password }}
        <div class="text-danger">
            {%if form.errors %}
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">{{forms.ValidationError}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label style="color:#222;">
                    <input type="checkbox" > Recordar?
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

when the informations is wrong redirec to /login, but no validate the inhow can i do the form validate before it reload the page?.

Comment: what do you mean with `relog the page` ?

Comment: @doniyor when i submit the form, this relog the index page and not validate